# Entity Framework Table Name Change

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a table named X that is already mapped to my Entity Model. I want to change the name of the table to Y in the database and Y in my entity model.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Is the best thing to delete the

Comment: As someone just answered-then-deleted, you can also edit the .edmx file. But I've had mixed success doing that - I've always managed to miss something and ended up with a broken .edmx. If you want to try that then make sure you have a backup, and it may well be easiest to delete the table and update. However you will lose any customisation you've made to navigation properties (names, types, IDs vs entity joins etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the?

If you eman entity, then yes.  Assuming you're using database first approach, and your model does not require a lot of reconfiguration.  then update the model from db, and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to override a method in your DbContext class, based on the database you are connecting too.

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("yourNewTableName");
    }
}
```